# Apache won't start after installing PHP

Tags: windows-7, php, apache-http-server

I have a working installation of Apache 2.2.17 on Windows 7, and I installed PHP 5.3.5 (the VC6, x86, thread-safe version)

I make sure to choose Apache 2.2.x as my web server and chose the path to Apache2.2\conf for the Apache configuration path.

But now, when I try to start Apache, I get this error:

> ---------------------------
>   Error
>   ---------------------------
>   The requested operation has failed!
>   ---------------------------
>   OK
>   ---------------------------

Nothing is written to error.log

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to put php5apache2_2.dll into my apache install folder and go into httpd.conf and change the "PhpIniDir" variable to be the path to the php.ini file in my PHP install folder.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is no need to copy the files.  You simply need to provide the correct paths.  I did not change any of the defaults when installing, and in my case the edits look like this in the httpd.conf file:

```
#BEGIN PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL
PHPIniDir "C:\Program Files\PHP"
LoadModule php5_module "C:\Program Files\PHP\php5apache2_2.dll"
#END PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL
```

Kind of annoying that the installer doesn't do this correctly in the first place given that it has all the required info...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I fixed it.

In my folder `Apache2.2\conf` I have a file `httpd.conf` and in the folder `Apache2.2\conf\original` is the same file. You have to change only the file in the second folder.

At the end of this file write:

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll" 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/PHP"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but after I added these following lines to configure:

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

After I added those lines, and I try to restart, I got this problem:

```
The requested operation has failed!
```

I solved with adding a hash (`#`) in front of each line and fixed it like this:

```
# LoadModule php5_module "C:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
# AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
# PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

You only need to add a hash `#` and restart it. It worked for me.

Comment: Adding a # in front of those lines comments them out and therefor does not load PHP. This will fix the problem but you now have the problem of not having PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem long before because of some modules conflict.
Just disable these modules from php.ini by adding semicolon before them.

```
;extension=php_mssql.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll 
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll 
;extension=php_pdo_oci8.dll 
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite_external.dll 
;extension=php_pspell.dll 
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
```

Save php.ini and then restart Apache. It will work like a charm.